# How to index a table with several ORDER BY clauses?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

I have a table IntradayPrices1Minute where I store 1 minute timeframe open, high, low and close prices for stocks:

```
CREATE TABLE `IntradayPrices1Minute` (
  `ticker` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `volume` mediumint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `open` decimal(8,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `high` decimal(8,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `low` decimal(8,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `close` decimal(8,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ticker`,`datetime`),
  UNIQUE KEY `indxTickerDatetime` (`ticker`,`datetime`)
)
```

I have build a query where I can calculate the **daily** open, high, low and close prices for those stocks. This is the query:

```
select 
    `IntradayPrices1Minute`.`ticker` AS `ticker`,
    cast(`IntradayPrices1Minute`.`datetime` as date) AS `Date`,
    substring_index(group_concat(cast(`IntradayPrices1Minute`.`open` as char charset utf8) order by `IntradayPrices1Minute`.`datetime` ASC separator ','),',',1) AS `Daily Open`,
    max(greatest(`IntradayPrices1Minute`.`open`,`IntradayPrices1Minute`.`high`,`IntradayPrices1Minute`.`low`,`IntradayPrices1Minute`.`close`)) AS `Daily High`,
    min(least(`IntradayPrices1Minute`.`open`,`IntradayPrices1Minute`.`high`,`IntradayPrices1Minute`.`low`,`IntradayPrices1Minute`.`close`)) AS `Daily Low`,
    substring_index(group_concat(cast(`IntradayPrices1Minute`.`close` as char charset utf8) 

order by 
   `IntradayPrices1Minute`.`datetime` DESC separator ','),',',1) AS `Daily Close` 
from    
   `IntradayPrices1Minute` 

group by 
   `IntradayPrices1Minute`.`ticker`,
   cast(`IntradayPrices1Minute`.`datetime` as date)
```

and this is part of the results that I got when I only had 4-5 days of data(as of today I have many more days of data):

```
ticker  Date        Open    High    Low     Close
----    ----------  ------  ------  ------  ------ 
AAAE    2012-11-26  0.0100  0.0100  0.0100  0.0100
AAAE    2012-11-27  0.0130  0.0140  0.0083  0.0140
AAAE    2012-11-28  0.0140  0.0175  0.0140  0.0165
AAAE    2012-11-29  0.0175  0.0175  0.0137  0.0137
AAMRQ   2012-11-26  0.4411  0.5300  0.4411  0.5290
AAMRQ   2012-11-27  0.5100  0.5110  0.4610  0.4950
AAMRQ   2012-11-28  0.4820  0.4900  0.4300  0.4640
AAMRQ   2012-11-29  0.4505  0.4590  0.4411  0.4590
AAMRQ   2012-11-30  0.4500  0.4570  0.4455  0.4568
```

So as of today the `IntradayPrices1Minute` table has already **9625952** records and growing by approx. 350000 records each day

Executing the previous SELECT with a LIMIT 1000 already takes more than 8 seconds, so I figured out some indexes are needed, however my knowledge of indexes and how to decide on them is very limited.

Some info I believe might be useful for those of you with more expertise on this:

```
show indexes from IntradayPrices1Minute
```

returns:

```
IntradayPrices1Minute   0   PRIMARY 1   ticker  A   32368               BTREE       
IntradayPrices1Minute   0   PRIMARY 2   datetime    A   9872508             BTREE       
IntradayPrices1Minute   0   indxTickerDatetime  1   ticker  A   21793               BTREE       
IntradayPrices1Minute   0   indxTickerDatetime  2   datetime    A   9872508             BTREE
```

and the show profiling command displays:

```
Status                 Duration
------                 --------
starting               0.000055
checking permission    0.000003
Opening tables         0.000018
System lock            0.000005
init                   0.000022
optimizing             0.000004
statistics             0.000011
preparing              0.000006
executing              0.000027
Sorting result         8.533655
Sending data           0.233446
end                    0.000010
removing tmp table     0.000006
end                    0.000007
removing tmp table     0.000002
end                    0.000005
query end              0.000003
closing tables         0.000004
freeing items          0.000041
logging slow query     0.000002
cleaning up            0.000003
```

Unfortunately this info is not of much use to me due to my limited knowledge. I suspect that all those ORDER BY might be what is being so intensive, because the show profiling states that 8,53 seconds are used "Sorting result" but I don´t know how to approach this to make the query efficient.

Thank you very much for any suggestions, specially if it helps me understand better indexing for future queries that I might also need to troubleshoot.

cheers,
Boga

Answer (score 2):

Try to change

```
GROUP BY ticker, date(datetime)
```

into

```
GROUP BY ticker, datetime
```

The first is not using your index and so a (very slow) file sort is needed. The second is using the index and much faster.

You can find such problems using:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table
```

Comment: I am so sorry... I had posted an older version of the query. I have edited my original post with the actual query that I have in production and now you can see that the query indeed groups by 2 fields that are indexed. So I don´t know why the more than 8 seconds sorting :-(

Comment: The answer is still the same. You're index is not used (as seen using the EXPLAIN option) because your casting the 'datetime' field. 

This will work and be a lot faster: `group by IntradayPrices1Minute.ticker,  IntradayPrices1Minute.datetime`

Comment: thank you. You were absolutely right! I don´t remember why I had a CAST for the date in the first place. In any case, it´s blazing fast now ;-)

Comment: DISREGARD: Now I remember why I had the CAST to date. It´s because I need to group by the date, not by the datetime. I now realize that doing what you suggested is giving me wrong results :-(

Comment: In  any case, I think that I will change the structure of the table to have date and time in separate columns, so never mind